# copy wordpress site files on new server

Tags: server, hosting

I need to copy a client's WordPress site onto my host's server.
This website is for development purposes and I will give it a new URL.

I have a copy of the wordpress/html files, but not the database. 
I don't need the database. I will use a new one - not worried about their existing content.

I understand I can move all of the wordpress/html files onto my host's server, but is there a correct way to do this?
I assume moving the files alone will not work, and something else will need to be done...not sure what that is though.

Comment: They might have plugin and website settings that you'll need, though. I'd recommend getting the database anyway, that way you know you're working on an exact copy of their live site.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a process that I use when I move a WP site from one place to another. I keep tweaking it, but the process has worked well for me many times.

There are plugins that purport to automate the move, but they didn't work for me, or they required premium ($) features to complete the process.

So I developed my own process, which you are welcome to 'borrow'. [Here](https://securitydawg.com/moving-a-wordpress-site/). It's based on Codex principles (mentioned in the other answer), but tweaked into a process that works for me.